# How to show woocommerce product sold quantity in last 24 hrs?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add a feature to my product detail page. I want the user can see Sold Quantity of the last 24 hrs.

For example, I add code into my function.php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'bbloomer_product_sold_count', 11 );

function bbloomer_product_sold_count() {
   global $product;
   $units_sold = $product->get_total_sales();
   if ( $units_sold ) echo '<div class="itemSold">' . sprintf( __( '%s Sold Items', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</div>';
}
```

This is showing me all the time sold quantity but I want the last 24 hr. Please guide me on how we can do this really appreciate this. Advance Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you can query it manual from the database and build the function like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'bbloomer_product_sold_count', 11 );

function bbloomer_product_sold_count() {
    global $product;
    global $wpdb;

    $product_id = $product->id();
    $date_to = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+24 hours'));
    $date_from = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $sql = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS sale_count
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS order_items
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS order_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_meta.order_item_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_meta.meta_value = posts.ID
    WHERE order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
    AND order_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
    AND order_meta.meta_value = %d
    AND order_items.order_id IN (
        SELECT posts.ID AS post_id
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
            AND posts.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
            AND DATE(posts.post_date) BETWEEN %s AND %s
    )
    GROUP BY order_meta.meta_value";
    $units_sold = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $product_id, $date_from, $date_to));
    if ( $units_sold ) echo '<div class="itemSold">' . sprintf( __( '%s Sold Items', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</div>';
}
```

because woocommerce doesn't provide the function for your case

Comment: While this is cool that it can be done, won't this kinda query running on every page load slow down OPs website?

Comment: Maybe you can try to cache the query result i think

Comment: If they have to use this, then for sure they should use the transient API.

Comment: yeah i think they shoud use  the transient API for this case to speed up the query time.